# Facebook Audience Network

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network

[image]

My question is in the estimated revenue section on the graph its showing estimated revenue but on top of the section its showing 0$. What could be the problem or is it not a problem.?

Waiting for your kind response.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No its not a poblem.

Facebook audience network shows your estimated revenue as a integer.So your estimated revenue not showing as a decimal number.
Then you can view your estimated revune in graph until reach.

Hope you helpful .